# Complementary symmetry class AB push pull amplifier

Tags: amplifier, power-electronics

[image]

How the two resistors r1 and r2 are used to maintain the base voltage of Q1 and Q2 0.7 and -0.7V respectively? I need the voltage divider formula that can calculate the base voltages for both transistors given two dc voltages +vcc and -vcc?
[image]

Also explain me why diodes are used and how those diode are conducting when there is no input signal. If there anyone can give me mathematical formula for the explanation i will be really helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: That's a relatively impractical circuit (both.) But as a behavioral or educational model of sorts, it is okay. 2nd case and without an input the resistors are connected between the rails with just two diodes included. The diodes will get current, just fine.

Answer (score 4):

In the following two systems, there is a potential difference between top and bottom nodes of \$(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC}) = 2V_{CC}\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWGpuH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because the top node has the higher potential, current will flow downwards through all the components between them. On the left, the current will depend entirely on the three resistances R1, R2 and R3. On the right R4 and R5 also permit current to flow, and control the amount that flows, but in this instance that current must also flow via the diodes.

The diodes do not oppose that current, since they are orientated to permit flow in that direction, and like all regular silicon diodes, when any substantial current flows through in their "forward" direction, they will each adopt a potential difference across them of approximately 0.7V, as shown.

Therefore, we can say that as long as there is current flowing through those diodes, there will be \$0.7V + 0.7V = 1.4V\$ difference between nodes C and D.

This property of diodes is how it is possible to predict that the bases of the two transistors will be separated in potential by 1.4V, or, in other words, \$V_C - V_D = 1.4V\$. This does not tell you anything about their absolute potentials, only the *difference* between them.

The absolute potentials \$V_C\$ and \$V_D\$ of nodes C and D depend on R4 and R5, and the supply potentials \$+V_{CC}\$ and \$-V_{CC}\$, but if the supply is symmetrical, such as ±12V, and R4 and R5 are equal in value, *and* as long as there is no input signal, then by that symmetry we can predict that \$V_C = +0.7V\$ and \$V_D=-0.7V\$. Obviously an input signal will cause \$V_C\$ and \$V_D\$ to fluctuate around those values.

---

For the left circuit, containing only resistances, and where the central resistance R2 is responsible for determining the potential difference \$V_A-V_B\$, we don't have the convenience of diode behavior, and we will have to resort to precise calculation of an appropriate value for R2.

For that, we can refer to the resistor potential divider principle, which tells us that each resistance in the chain will develop a potential difference in proportion to its resistance. That is:

$$ V_{R1} : V_{R2} : V_{R3} = R_1 : R_2 : R_3 $$

This means that the total voltage \$(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC})\$ is shared between them:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= \left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC})\right]\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} \\ \\
V_{R2} &= \left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC})\right]\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} \\ \\
V_{R3} &= \left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC})\right]\frac{R_3}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You are interested in only the voltage across the central resistance R2, which you require to be 1.4V. Therefore you need to ensure this condition is true:

$$ \left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC})\right]\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3} = 1.4V $$

To simplify matters, if the supply is symmetrical, such as \$+V_{CC}=+5V\$, and \$-V_{CC}=-5V\$, then you have \$(+V_{CC}) - (-V_{CC})=2\times 5V=10V\$ total across the entire chain. Also we may assume that \$R_1 = R_3 = R\$ and this above equation boils down to:

$$
\begin{aligned}
10\frac{R_2}{R_2 + 2R} &= 1.4V \\ \\
\frac{R_2}{R_2 + 2R} &= 0.14 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now it's just a question of choosing \$R_2\$ and \$R\$ to produce an appropriate current in the chain, while also satisfying that above condition.

---

Everything I've said above is contingent upon there being *no* current drawn away from, or injected into, any node in those chains. This, of course, won't be the case. There are input currents to and from nodes A, B, C and D, and there are transistor bases drawing/injecting current too. These influences must also be considered, to understand the full picture, and to be able to calculate the resistances, which is a whole other story.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your first circuit is suitable for teaching but not production .Small vbe changes from supply voltage changes will cause big Ic changes .Small temp increases cause big Ic increase leading to thermal runaway.If you still want to apply the first circuit consider emmiter resistors and/or NTC for R2 .Your formulae has a nasty exponent in it .The second circuit that has the diodes is better .It is a current mirror so if the diode has the same curve as the transistor the mirror gain will be one making collector current equal to R1 current at idle .Such a match is very good inside chips but not too good with discrete parts .Diode connected transistors are good for the diodes ,or you can use a rubber diode for D1.D2 .A rubber diode is also called a Vbe multiplier.What I do on the car radio stuff is rubber diode on main heatsink and emmiter resistors.

Comment: Here is an explanation for "rubber diode" (basically a resistor-programmable voltage reference).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_diode  Also, small emitter resistors can be used to provide some negative feedback for stabilization.

Answer (score 1):

Both transistors are emitter followers, so for Q1 the potential of base is same as emitter (-0.7V of course).
For Q2 the potential of emitter is +0.7V of base.
So the resistor divider holds the bases and the emitters also (as I mention) at fixed potential, usually in the middle of rails.
With diodes it is the same.
The problem is if voltage across R2 is more than 1.4V because a huge current starts to flow through transistors, even with no signal.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mjJq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Input and output voltage]

[image: Input and output current]

This shows a simple way to obtain high current gain with DC coupling and minimal crossover distortion. However, it performs best when input voltage is high enough to forward bias the base-emitter junctions. This may not exactly answer the OP's questions, but provides an idea that may prove useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation